# how to change root pass word in ubuntu 16.04 LTS on SAMSUNG Linux On Dex

Tags: 16.04, password, arm

I am trying to change root password in my Ubuntu .

This is what I did:
1: installed linux on dex on google play
2: downloaded the ubuntu 16.04 LTS arm image
3: After starting the image in linux on dex, enter the graphical interface directly.
       I don't know the passwords of the current users ‘dextop’ and ‘root’ users. How can I change their passwords?

```
sudo su passwd root
```

it dones't work ,becaus I also don't know the password of the current user.

I can't start single-user mode and repair mode, and I can't change the password of any user without knowing the current user password.
Sorry, my english sucks, will there be any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From googling the default password seems to be `secret`. See [here](https://www.linuxondex.com/), you have to scroll down a bit but it says that the sudo password for Linux on DeX is secret.

Afterwards you can do `sudo passwd root` (NOT `sudo su passwd root`, not sure what `su` is doing there) to change password of root user.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks, very helpful, I revisited the website and they provided the default root password.  *Sudo password for Linux on DeX is 'secret'.